# plotly html figures don't rendered in some browsers (EDGE/CHROME)

Tags: javascript, python, html, plotly

When I generate a HTML file with many Plotly figures or even with few figures but much data points then such file is not properly rendered by some browsers (EDGE, CHROME).
The effect is that some plots are empty or some times are slow to interact.

The point is that with Firefox all the plots are rendered and fluid.

Does anyone know the reason?is there any way to optimize the browser to interpret the HTML and javascript generated by Plotly?

Here a sample of the HTML. the full HTML would be multiple elements like the one showed (notice I've shortened the length of the arrays due to SO limits)

```
<div>                        <script type="text/javascript">window.PlotlyConfig = {MathJaxConfig: 'local'};</script>
    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.18.2.min.js"></script>                <div id=4dc988c0-5576-47b1-897e-2d0ce27cd2a3 class=plotly-graph-div style="height:500px; width:1600px;"></div>            <script type="text/javascript">                                    window.PLOTLYENV=window.PLOTLYENV || {};                                    if (document.getElementById("4dc988c0-5576-47b1-897e-2d0ce27cd2a3")) {                    Plotly.newPlot(                        "4dc988c0-5576-47b1-897e-2d0ce27cd2a3",                        [{"legendgroup":"0.0","line":{"color":"#636efa","dash":"solid","shape":"hv"},"marker":{"symbol":"circle","size":3.5},"mode":"markers+lines","name":"StaId_0","showlegend":true,"x":[44480.573,44485.717,44491.08,44496.335,44501.426,44506.559,44511.659,44516.794,44521.948,44527.047,44532.201,44537.391,44542.535,44547.634,44552.77,44557.95,44563.06,44568.223,44573.403,44578.557,44583.785,44588.92,44594.293,44599.569,44604.661,44609.743,44614.824,44619.916,44625.711,44630.875,44636.02,44641.137,44646.308,44651.39,44656.517,44661.644,44666.743,44671.879,44676.997,44682.204,44687.35,44692.46,44697.866,44703.145,44708.254,44713.363,44718.518,44726.852,44732.186,44737.563,44742.726,44747.843,44752.925,44758.096,44763.187,44768.413,44773.797,44779.136,44784.251,44789.384,44794.589,44799.974,44805.214,44810.319,44815.416,44820.587,44825.797,44830.883,44835.962,44841.058,44846.244,44851.393,44856.597,44862.498,44867.909,44872.988,44878.111,44883.399,44889.185,44894.338,44899.484,44904.929,44910.183,44915.339,44920.429,44925.575,44930.659,44935.814,44940.934,44946.017,44951.1,44956.22,44961.384,44966.555,44971.737,44976.821,44992.09,44997.253,45002.343,45007.659,45012.757,45017.919,45022.917,45027.995,45033.154,45038.286,45043.373,45048.487,45053.636,45058.781,45063.976,45069.108,45074.249,45079.363,45084.46,45089.613,45094.743,45099.956,45105.061,45110.411,45115.578,45120.783,45125.915,45131.042,45136.125,45141.284,45146.479,45151.629,45156.761,45161.947,45167.079,45172.193,45177.325,45182.467,45187.544,45192.667,45197.81,45202.915,45208.264,45213.594,45218.789,45223.921,45229.045,45234.141,45239.318,45248.772,45254.225,45259.401,45264.479,45269.584,45274.752,45279.947,45285.089,45290.221,45295.308,45300.445,45305.549,45310.709,45316.118,45321.412,45326.526,45331.641,45336.8,45341.914,45347.018,45352.187,45357.346,45362.451,45367.529,45372.688,45377.927,45384.725,45389.822,45395.026,45400.62,45406.038,45411.24,45416.721,45421.862,45426.976,45432.072,45437.258,45442.366,45447.441,45452.564,45457.642,45462.819,45467.96,45473.102,45478.233,45483.356,45488.442,45493.548,45498.645,45506.098,45511.492,45517.047,45522.26,45527.419,45532.533,45537.657,45542.9,45548.082,45553.178,45558.31,45563.424,45568.529,45573.679,45578.802,45583.979,45589.147,45594.37,45599.448,45604.607,45609.798,45614.992,45620.321,45625.498,45630.702,45635.825,45640.978,45646.161,45651.339,45656.534,45661.648,45666.843,45672.011,45677.206,45682.293,45687.415,45692.493,45697.654,45702.812,45707.91,45713.015,45718.137,45723.469,45728.655,45733.778,45738.991,45744.088,45749.193,45754.298,45759.52,45764.602,45769.753,45774.948,45780.134,45785.266,45790.406,45795.566,45800.662,45805.813,45810.919,45816.005,45821.237,45826.577,45831.746,45836.859,45841.938,45847.024,45852.103,45857.271,45862.412,45867.583,45872.729,45877.907,45883.003,45888.189,45893.311,45898.416,45903.531,45908.882,45913.971,45919.336,45924.424,45929.873,45935.08,45941.545,45947.076,45952.58,45957.805,45962.892,45967.987,45973.172,45978.331,45983.408,45988.495,45993.617,45998.785,46003.899,46008.983,46014.141,46019.239,46026.385,46031.705,46036.882,46041.986,46047.155,46052.369,46057.528,46062.606,46067.738,46072.879,46077.975,46083.07,46088.193,46093.389,46098.521,46103.662,46108.767,46113.971,46119.187,46124.291,46129.396,46134.754,46139.896,46145.018,46150.16,46155.255,46160.343,46165.421,46170.508,46175.667,46180.78,46185.912,46191.026,46196.211,46201.363,46206.477,46211.618,46216.749,46221.839,46227.025,46232.184,46237.56,46242.827,46248.004,46253.082,46258.17,46263.337,46268.469,46273.557,46278.691,46283.78,46288.876,46293.981,46299.095,46304.272,46309.416,46314.636,46319.858,46325.037,46330.169,46335.4,46340.758,46345.989,46351.103,46356.199,46361.331,46366.427,46371.514,46376.727,46381.959,46387.055,46392.241,46397.39,46402.522,46407.726,46412.876,46417.964,46423.114,46428.256,46433.335,46438.547,46443.897,46449.137,46454.666,46459.824,46465.352,46470.504,46475.762,46480.893,46486.028,46491.124,46496.255,46501.33,46506.58,46511.667,46516.808,46521.941,46527.308,46532.476,46537.554,46542.65,46548.017,46553.158,46558.236,46563.368,46568.555,46573.804,46578.917,46584.076,46589.163,46594.286,46599.382,46604.541,46609.664,46614.859,46619.975,46625.052,46630.249,46635.345,46640.486,46645.654,46651.084,46656.279,46661.41,46666.633,46671.747,46676.87,46682.021,46687.134,46692.248,46697.389,46702.567,46707.653,46712.74,46717.89,46723.031,46728.191,46733.289,46738.385,46743.553,46748.676,46754.098,46759.256,46764.486,46769.569,46774.657,46779.798,46784.876,46790.022,46795.139,46800.272,46805.437,46810.542,46815.754,46820.869,46825.964,46831.393,46836.411,46841.561,46846.666,46851.807,46857.237,46862.378,46867.609,46872.74,46877.82,46882.997,46888.127,46893.299,46898.375,46903.528,46908.722,46913.873,46918.947,46924.092,46929.176,46934.347,46939.464,46944.641,46949.745,46955.067,46960.465,46965.696,46970.792,46975.988,46981.174,46986.804,46992.002,46997.123,47002.299,47007.448,47012.581,47017.694,47022.8,47028.008,47033.168,47038.282,47043.435,47048.513,47053.689,47058.83,47064.156,47069.307,47074.511,47079.607,47084.875,47090.056,47095.13,47100.252,47105.34,47110.462,47115.648,47120.79,47126.047,47131.223,47136.383,47141.545,47146.654,47151.785,47156.869,47161.947,47167.314,47172.573,47177.659,47182.765,47187.842,47193.029,47198.179,47203.347,47208.443,47213.557,47218.743,47223.929,47229.07,47234.183,47239.351,47244.774,47249.87,47255.11,47260.318,47265.736,47271.13,47276.379,47281.493,47286.58,47291.758,47296.863,47302.049,47307.172,47312.313,47317.409,47326.577,47332.104,47337.245,47342.48,47347.727,47352.85,47357.973,47363.096,47368.264,47373.587,47378.727,47383.859,47389.027,47394.187,47399.409,47404.622,47409.709,47414.796,47419.901,47425.006,47430.084,47435.189,47440.266,47445.354,47450.633,47455.819,47461.096,47466.343,47471.692,47477.291,47482.334,47487.502,47492.643,47497.823,47503.026,47508.688,47514.287,47519.382,47524.508,47529.685,47534.789,47539.984,47545.124,47550.228,47555.443,47560.638,47565.778,47570.967,47576.075,47581.445,47586.602,47591.719,47596.844,47601.926,47607.097,47612.277,47617.346,47622.496,47627.595,47632.701,47637.91,47643.015,47648.112,47653.434,47658.512,47663.599,47668.75,47673.915,47679.092,47684.486,47689.69,47694.768,47699.891,47705.051,47710.173,47715.278,47720.401,47725.533,47730.666,47735.806,47740.939,47746.079,47751.176,47756.3,47761.379,47766.475,47771.615,47776.739,47781.827,47787.206,47792.38,47797.574,47802.661,47807.794,47812.934,47818.031,47823.109,47828.214,47833.391,47838.495,47843.984,47849.083,47854.22,47859.322,47864.437,47869.55,47874.629,47879.753,47884.956,47890.386,47895.599,47900.704,47905.818,47910.897,47916.128,47921.233,47926.41,47931.488,47936.592,47941.76,47946.892,47952.171,47957.228,47962.605,47967.755,47972.852,47977.93,47983.094,47988.257,47993.607,47999.191,48004.645,48009.841,48015.037,48020.949,48026.291,48031.72,48036.849,48041.966,48047.149,48052.296,48057.506,48063.258,48068.396,48073.489,48078.582,48083.77,48088.895,48094.31,48099.526,48104.65,48109.758,48114.926,48120.081,48125.3,48130.345,48135.426,48140.441,48145.537,48150.714,48155.792,48160.925,48166.031,48171.245,48176.323,48181.472,48186.658,48191.746,48197.122,48202.272,48207.44,48212.625,48217.802,48222.958,48228.086,48233.235,48238.379,48243.49,48248.595,48253.672,48258.814,48263.964,48269.052,48274.14,48279.317,48284.395,48289.518,48294.632,48300.001,48305.158,48310.29,48315.369,48320.447,48325.57,48330.82,48335.898,48341.065,48346.287,48351.392,48356.524,48361.979,48367.164,48372.298,48377.441,48382.514,48387.677,48392.772,48397.949,48403.359,48408.554,48413.767,48418.962,48424.111,48429.19,48434.287,48439.472,48444.631,48449.817,48454.931,48460.075,48465.195,48470.283,48475.641,48480.81,48486.122,48491.281,48496.504,48501.608,48507.11,48512.351,48517.518,48523.422,48528.602,48533.735,48538.858,48544.362,48549.47,48554.847,48560.019,48565.102,48570.182,48575.526,48580.697,48585.806,48590.895,48596.021,48601.102,48606.21,48611.598,48616.76,48624.851,48630.318,48635.507,48640.635,48645.743,48650.896,48656.184,48661.325,48666.395,48671.481,48676.622,48681.756,48686.998,48692.474,48697.624,48702.801,48708.041,48713.387,48718.556,48723.642,48728.738,48733.88,48739.048,48744.252,48749.411,48754.587,48759.693,48764.771,48769.858,48774.972,48780.34,48785.764,48791.027,48796.264,48801.532,48806.654,48811.748,48817.118,48822.361,48827.58,48832.676,48837.85,48843.017,48848.165,48853.268,48858.398,48863.547,48868.632,48873.708,48878.802,48884.069,48889.185,48894.392,48899.774,48904.886,48909.971,48915.084,48920.542,48925.788,48930.926,48936.046,48941.186,48946.28,48951.375,48956.514,48961.608,48966.747,48971.905,48977.088,48982.259,48987.341,48992.617,48997.765,49002.859,49008.178,49013.291,49018.403,49023.848,49029.276,49034.362,49039.704,49044.792,49049.912,49055.026,49060.166,49065.944,49070.959,49077.067,49082.161,49087.265,49092.378,49097.508,49102.585,49107.661,49112.746,49117.841,49122.952,49128.273,49133.457,49138.6,49143.69,49148.82,49153.896,49159.028,49164.139,49169.243,49174.382,49179.458,49184.687,49189.9,49194.994,49200.232,49205.499,49210.583,49215.687,49220.881,49226.046,49231.367,49236.677,49241.96,49247.045,49252.13,49257.216,49262.568,49267.91,49273.208,49278.524,49283.695,49288.888,49293.999,49299.303,49304.411,49309.655,49314.916,49320.205,49325.512,49330.719,49336.054,49341.486,49346.589,49351.704,49356.849,49362.104,49367.201,49372.337,49377.419,49382.572,49387.852,49392.934,49398.061,49403.479,49408.606,49413.778,49418.878,49423.986,49429.086,49434.231,49439.556,49444.764,49449.846,49454.954,49460.162,49465.369,49470.497,49475.623,49480.768,49485.903,49491.021,49496.654,49501.762],"xaxis":"x","y":[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,2.0,86.0,163.0,229.0,287.0,339.0,384.0,423.0,456.0,483.0,504.0,518.0,526.0,532.0,537.0,542.0,542.0,538.0,526.0,512.0,497.0,478.0,457.0,434.0,410.0,382.0,354.0,328.0,302.0,278.0,256.0,236.0,218.0,201.0,185.0,171.0,158.0,146.0,135.0,125.0,115.0,106.0,98.0,91.0,84.0,78.0,72.0,67.0,62.0,58.0,54.0,50.0,46.0,43.0,40.0,37.0,35.0,33.0,31.0,29.0,27.0,25.0,23.0,22.0,21.0,20.0,19.0,18.0,17.0,16.0,15.0,14.0,13.0,12.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,2.0,51.0,96.0,138.0,176.0,162.0,150.0,138.0,127.0,117.0,108.0,100.0,92.0,85.0,79.0,73.0,68.0,63.0,58.0,54.0,50.0,46.0,43.0,40.0,37.0,35.0,33.0,31.0,29.0,27.0,25.0,23.0,22.0,21.0,20.0,19.0,18.0,17.0,16.0,15.0,14.0,13.0,12.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,2.0,86.0,162.0,226.0,282.0,331.0,371.0,406.0,434.0,459.0,478.0,491.0,500.0,505.0,506.0,504.0,499.0,493.0,484.0,473.0,463.0,449.0,431.0,412.0,392.0,369.0,346.0,323.0,298.0,275.0,253.0,233.0,215.0,198.0,183.0,169.0,156.0,144.0,133.0,123.0,114.0,105.0,97.0,90.0,83.0,77.0,71.0,66.0,61.0,57.0,53.0,49.0,46.0,43.0,40.0,37.0,35.0,33.0,31.0,29.0,27.0,25.0,23.0,22.0,21.0,20.0,19.0,18.0,17.0,16.0,15.0,14.0,13.0,12.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.0,84.0,154.0,216.0,268.0,315.0,354.0,385.0,411.0,430.0,444.0,454.0,459.0,461.0,458.0,454.0,446.0,438.0,428.0,416.0,402.0,385.0,365.0,342.0,317.0,294.0,271.0,250.0,230.0,212.0,196.0,181.0,167.0,154.0,142.0,131.0,121.0,112.0,104.0,96.0,89.0,82.0,76.0,70.0,65.0,60.0,56.0,52.0,48.0,45.0,42.0,39.0,36.0,34.0,32.0,30.0,28.0,26.0,24.0,23.0,22.0,21.0,20.0,19.0,18.0,17.0,16.0,15.0,14.0,13.0,12.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.0,86.0,162.0,226.0,282.0,329.0,369.0,401.0,428.0,449.0,465.0,478.0,488.0,494.0,497.0,500.0,500.0,497.0,493.0,489.0,484.0,478.0,470.0,460.0,451.0,442.0,434.0,425.0,411.0,396.0,380.0,363.0,345.0,328.0,310.0,292.0,273.0,254.0,236.0,220.0,203.0,187.0,173.0,160.0,148.0,137.0,127.0,117.0,108.0,100.0,92.0,85.0,79.0,73.0,68.0,63.0,58.0,54.0,50.0,46.0,43.0,40.0,37.0,35.0,33.0,31.0,29.0,27.0,25.0,23.0,22.0,21.0,20.0,19.0,18.0,17.0,16.0,15.0,14.0,13.0,12.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.0,4.0,88.0,163.0,226.0,282.0,329.0,369.0,403.0,433.0,459.0,483.0,503.0,57.0,110.0,159.0,204.0,245.0,283.0,318.0,350.0,379.0,406.0,431.0,454.0,475.0,494.0,512.0,529.0,544.0,558.0,571.0,526.0,484.0,446.0,411.0,379.0,349.0,322.0,297.0,274.0,253.0,233.0,215.0,198.0,183.0,169.0,156.0,144.0,133.0,123.0,114.0,105.0,97.0,90.0,83.0,77.0,71.0,66.0,61.0,57.0,53.0,49.0,46.0,43.0,40.0,37.0,35.0,33.0,31.0,29.0,27.0,25.0,23.0,22.0,21.0,20.0,19.0,18.0,17.0,16.0,15.0,14.0,13.0,12.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.0,4.0,92.0,173.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.0,4.0,6.0,94.0,175.0,249.0,318.0,381.0,439.0,492.0,541.0,586.0,628.0,578.0,532.0,490.0,451.0,415.0,382.0,352.0,324.0,299.0,276.0,254.0,234.0,216.0,199.0,184.0,170.0,157.0,145.0,134.0,124.0,115.0,106.0,98.0,91.0,84.0,78.0,72.0,67.0,62.0,58.0,54.0,50.0,46.0,43.0,40.0,37.0,35.0,33.0,31.0,29.0,27.0,25.0,23.0,22.0,21.0,20.0,19.0,18.0,17.0,16.0,15.0,14.0,13.0,12.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.0,4.0,6.0,94.0,175.0,249.0,318.0,381.0,439.0,492.0,541.0,586.0,540.0,497.0,458.0,422.0,389.0,358.0,330.0,304.0,280.0,258.0,238.0,219.0,202.0,186.0,172.0,159.0,147.0,136.0,126.0,116.0,107.0,99.0,92.0,85.0,79.0,73.0,68.0,63.0,58.0,54.0,50.0,46.0,43.0,40.0,37.0,35.0,33.0,31.0,29.0,27.0,25.0,23.0,22.0,21.0,20.0,19.0,18.0,17.0,16.0,15.0,14.0,13.0,12.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,75.0,136.0,188.0,230.0,261.0,285.0,302.0,309.0,311.0,308.0,298.0,283.0,261.0,241.0,222.0,205.0,189.0,174.0,161.0,149.0,138.0,127.0,117.0,108.0,100.0,92.0,85.0,79.0,73.0,68.0,63.0,58.0,54.0,50.0,46.0,43.0,40.0,37.0,35.0,33.0,31.0,29.0,27.0,25.0,23.0,22.0,21.0,20.0,19.0,18.0,17.0,16.0,15.0,14.0,13.0,12.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.0,4.0,6.0,8.0,45.0,79.0,110.0,139.0,165.0,152.0,140.0,129.0,119.0,110.0,102.0,94.0,87.0,81.0,75.0,69.0,64.0,59.0,55.0,51.0,47.0,44.0,41.0,38.0,35.0,33.0,31.0,29.0,27.0,25.0,23.0,22.0,21.0,20.0,19.0,18.0,17.0,16.0,15.0,14.0,13.0,12.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.0,4.0,6.0,8.0,92.0,167.0,230.0,286.0,333.0,373.0,405.0,432.0,451.0,463.0,472.0,476.0,476.0,471.0,464.0,452.0,439.0,421.0,401.0,379.0,354.0,328.0,302.0,278.0,256.0,236.0,218.0,201.0,185.0,171.0,158.0,146.0,135.0,125.0,115.0,106.0,98.0,91.0,84.0,78.0,72.0,67.0,62.0,58.0,54.0,50.0,46.0,43.0,40.0,37.0,35.0,33.0,31.0,29.0,27.0,25.0,23.0,22.0,21.0,20.0,19.0,18.0,17.0,16.0,15.0,14.0,13.0,12.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.0,4.0,6.0,8.0,68.0,123.0,114.0,105.0,97.0,90.0,83.0,77.0,71.0,66.0,61.0,57.0,53.0,49.0,46.0,43.0,40.0,37.0,35.0,33.0,31.0,29.0,27.0,25.0,23.0,22.0,21.0,20.0,19.0,18.0,17.0,16.0,15.0,14.0,13.0,12.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.0,4.0,6.0,8.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,55.0,106.0,153.0,196.0,236.0,273.0,307.0,338.0,366.0,392.0,416.0,438.0,458.0,477.0,494.0,510.0,525.0,538.0,495.0,456.0,420.0,387.0,357.0,329.0,303.0,279.0,257.0,237.0,219.0,202.0,186.0,172.0,159.0,147.0,136.0,126.0,116.0,107.0,99.0,92.0,85.0,79.0,73.0,68.0,63.0,58.0,54.0,50.0,46.0,43.0,40.0,37.0,35.0,33.0,31.0,29.0,27.0,25.0,23.0,22.0,21.0,20.0,19.0,18.0,17.0,16.0,15.0,14.0,13.0,12.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,88.0,169.0,244.0,313.0,376.0,434.0,488.0,537.0,583.0,625.0,663.0,698.0,731.0,761.0,789.0,814.0,837.0,771.0,710.0,654.0,602.0,554.0,510.0,470.0,433.0,399.0,368.0,339.0,312.0,288.0,265.0,244.0,225.0,207.0,191.0,176.0,162.0,150.0,138.0,127.0,117.0,108.0,100.0,92.0,85.0,79.0,73.0,68.0,63.0,58.0,54.0,50.0,46.0,43.0,40.0,37.0,35.0,33.0,31.0,29.0,27.0,25.0,23.0,22.0,21.0,20.0,19.0,18.0,17.0,16.0,15.0,14.0,13.0,12.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.0,4.0,6.0,8.0,92.0,167.0,230.0,286.0,333.0,373.0,405.0,432.0,451.0,463.0,472.0,476.0,476.0,471.0,464.0,452.0,439.0,421.0,401.0,379.0,354.0,328.0,302.0,278.0,256.0,236.0,218.0,201.0,185.0,171.0,158.0,146.0,135.0,125.0,115.0,106.0,98.0,91.0,84.0,78.0,72.0,67.0,62.0,58.0,54.0,50.0,46.0,43.0,40.0,37.0,35.0,33.0,31.0,29.0,27.0,25.0,23.0,22.0,21.0,20.0,19.0,18.0,17.0,16.0,15.0,14.0,13.0,12.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,88.0,163.0,226.0,282.0,329.0,369.0,401.0,428.0,447.0,460.0,470.0,474.0,475.0,470.0,463.0,451.0,438.0,420.0,400.0,378.0,353.0,327.0,301.0,277.0,255.0,235.0,217.0,200.0,184.0,170.0,157.0,145.0,134.0,124.0,115.0,106.0,98.0,91.0,84.0,78.0,72.0,67.0,62.0,58.0,54.0,50.0,46.0,43.0,40.0,37.0,35.0,33.0,31.0,29.0,27.0,25.0,23.0,22.0,21.0,20.0,19.0,18.0,17.0,16.0,15.0,14.0,13.0,12.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.0,4.0,6.0,6.0,6.0,6.0,6.0,6.0,6.0,6.0,6.0,6.0,6.0,6.0,6.0,6.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,4.0,4.0,4.0,4.0,4.0,4.0,4.0,4.0,4.0,4.0,4.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0],"yaxis":"y","type":"scattergl","visible":false}],                        {"template":{"data":{"histogram2dcontour":[{"type":"histogram2dcontour","colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""},"colorscale":[[0.0,"#0d0887"],[0.1111111111111111,"#46039f"],[0.2222222222222222,"#7201a8"],[0.3333333333333333,"#9c179e"],[0.4444444444444444,"#bd3786"],[0.5555555555555556,"#d8576b"],[0.6666666666666666,"#ed7953"],[0.7777777777777778,"#fb9f3a"],[0.8888888888888888,"#fdca26"],[1.0,"#f0f921"]]}],"choropleth":[{"type":"choropleth","colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}],"histogram2d":[{"type":"histogram2d","colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""},"colorscale":[[0.0,"#0d0887"],[0.1111111111111111,"#46039f"],[0.2222222222222222,"#7201a8"],[0.3333333333333333,"#9c179e"],[0.4444444444444444,"#bd3786"],[0.5555555555555556,"#d8576b"],[0.6666666666666666,"#ed7953"],[0.7777777777777778,"#fb9f3a"],[0.8888888888888888,"#fdca26"],[1.0,"#f0f921"]]}],"heatmap":[{"type":"heatmap","colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""},"colorscale":[[0.0,"#0d0887"],[0.1111111111111111,"#46039f"],[0.2222222222222222,"#7201a8"],[0.3333333333333333,"#9c179e"],[0.4444444444444444,"#bd3786"],[0.5555555555555556,"#d8576b"],[0.6666666666666666,"#ed7953"],[0.7777777777777778,"#fb9f3a"],[0.8888888888888888,"#fdca26"],[1.0,"#f0f921"]]}],"heatmapgl":[{"type":"heatmapgl","colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""},"colorscale":[[0.0,"#0d0887"],[0.1111111111111111,"#46039f"],[0.2222222222222222,"#7201a8"],[0.3333333333333333,"#9c179e"],[0.4444444444444444,"#bd3786"],[0.5555555555555556,"#d8576b"],[0.6666666666666666,"#ed7953"],[0.7777777777777778,"#fb9f3a"],[0.8888888888888888,"#fdca26"],[1.0,"#f0f921"]]}],"contourcarpet":[{"type":"contourcarpet","colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}],"contour":[{"type":"contour","colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""},"colorscale":[[0.0,"#0d0887"],[0.1111111111111111,"#46039f"],[0.2222222222222222,"#7201a8"],[0.3333333333333333,"#9c179e"],[0.4444444444444444,"#bd3786"],[0.5555555555555556,"#d8576b"],[0.6666666666666666,"#ed7953"],[0.7777777777777778,"#fb9f3a"],[0.8888888888888888,"#fdca26"],[1.0,"#f0f921"]]}],"surface":[{"type":"surface","colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""},"colorscale":[[0.0,"#0d0887"],[0.1111111111111111,"#46039f"],[0.2222222222222222,"#7201a8"],[0.3333333333333333,"#9c179e"],[0.4444444444444444,"#bd3786"],[0.5555555555555556,"#d8576b"],[0.6666666666666666,"#ed7953"],[0.7777777777777778,"#fb9f3a"],[0.8888888888888888,"#fdca26"],[1.0,"#f0f921"]]}],"mesh3d":[{"type":"mesh3d","colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}],"scatter":[{"fillpattern":{"fillmode":"overlay","size":10,"solidity":0.2},"type":"scatter"}],"parcoords":[{"type":"parcoords","line":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}}],"scatterpolargl":[{"type":"scatterpolargl","marker":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}}],"bar":[{"error_x":{"color":"#2a3f5f"},"error_y":{"color":"#2a3f5f"},"marker":{"line":{"color":"#E5ECF6","width":0.5},"pattern":{"fillmode":"overlay","size":10,"solidity":0.2}},"type":"bar"}],"scattergeo":[{"type":"scattergeo","marker":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}}],"scatterpolar":[{"type":"scatterpolar","marker":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}}],"histogram":[{"marker":{"pattern":{"fillmode":"overlay","size":10,"solidity":0.2}},"type":"histogram"}],"scattergl":[{"type":"scattergl","marker":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}}],"scatter3d":[{"type":"scatter3d","line":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}},"marker":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}}],"scattermapbox":[{"type":"scattermapbox","marker":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}}],"scatterternary":[{"type":"scatterternary","marker":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}}],"scattercarpet":[{"type":"scattercarpet","marker":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}}],"carpet":[{"aaxis":{"endlinecolor":"#2a3f5f","gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","minorgridcolor":"white","startlinecolor":"#2a3f5f"},"baxis":{"endlinecolor":"#2a3f5f","gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","minorgridcolor":"white","startlinecolor":"#2a3f5f"},"type":"carpet"}],"table":[{"cells":{"fill":{"color":"#EBF0F8"},"line":{"color":"white"}},"header":{"fill":{"color":"#C8D4E3"},"line":{"color":"white"}},"type":"table"}],"barpolar":[{"marker":{"line":{"color":"#E5ECF6","width":0.5},"pattern":{"fillmode":"overlay","size":10,"solidity":0.2}},"type":"barpolar"}],"pie":[{"automargin":true,"type":"pie"}]},"layout":{"autotypenumbers":"strict","colorway":["#636efa","#EF553B","#00cc96","#ab63fa","#FFA15A","#19d3f3","#FF6692","#B6E880","#FF97FF","#FECB52"],"font":{"color":"#2a3f5f"},"hovermode":"closest","hoverlabel":{"align":"left"},"paper_bgcolor":"white","plot_bgcolor":"#E5ECF6","polar":{"bgcolor":"#E5ECF6","angularaxis":{"gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","ticks":""},"radialaxis":{"gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","ticks":""}},"ternary":{"bgcolor":"#E5ECF6","aaxis":{"gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","ticks":""},"baxis":{"gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","ticks":""},"caxis":{"gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","ticks":""}},"coloraxis":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}},"colorscale":{"sequential":[[0.0,"#0d0887"],[0.1111111111111111,"#46039f"],[0.2222222222222222,"#7201a8"],[0.3333333333333333,"#9c179e"],[0.4444444444444444,"#bd3786"],[0.5555555555555556,"#d8576b"],[0.6666666666666666,"#ed7953"],[0.7777777777777778,"#fb9f3a"],[0.8888888888888888,"#fdca26"],[1.0,"#f0f921"]],"sequentialminus":[[0.0,"#0d0887"],[0.1111111111111111,"#46039f"],[0.2222222222222222,"#7201a8"],[0.3333333333333333,"#9c179e"],[0.4444444444444444,"#bd3786"],[0.5555555555555556,"#d8576b"],[0.6666666666666666,"#ed7953"],[0.7777777777777778,"#fb9f3a"],[0.8888888888888888,"#fdca26"],[1.0,"#f0f921"]],"diverging":[[0,"#8e0152"],[0.1,"#c51b7d"],[0.2,"#de77ae"],[0.3,"#f1b6da"],[0.4,"#fde0ef"],[0.5,"#f7f7f7"],[0.6,"#e6f5d0"],[0.7,"#b8e186"],[0.8,"#7fbc41"],[0.9,"#4d9221"],[1,"#276419"]]},"xaxis":{"gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","ticks":"","title":{"standoff":15},"zerolinecolor":"white","automargin":true,"zerolinewidth":2},"yaxis":{"gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","ticks":"","title":{"standoff":15},"zerolinecolor":"white","automargin":true,"zerolinewidth":2},"scene":{"xaxis":{"backgroundcolor":"#E5ECF6","gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","showbackground":true,"ticks":"","zerolinecolor":"white","gridwidth":2},"yaxis":{"backgroundcolor":"#E5ECF6","gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","showbackground":true,"ticks":"","zerolinecolor":"white","gridwidth":2},"zaxis":{"backgroundcolor":"#E5ECF6","gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","showbackground":true,"ticks":"","zerolinecolor":"white","gridwidth":2}},"shapedefaults":{"line":{"color":"#2a3f5f"}},"annotationdefaults":{"arrowcolor":"#2a3f5f","arrowhead":0,"arrowwidth":1},"geo":{"bgcolor":"white","landcolor":"#E5ECF6","subunitcolor":"white","showland":true,"showlakes":true,"lakecolor":"white"},"title":{"x":0.05},"mapbox":{"style":"light"}}},"xaxis":{"anchor":"y","domain":[0.0,1.0],"title":{"text":"Time (ms)"},"range":[0.0,49502.692]},"yaxis":{"anchor":"x","domain":[0.0,1.0],"title":{"text":"UlNbiqAvg"}},"legend":{"title":{"text":"StaId"},"tracegroupgap":0,"yanchor":"top","xanchor":"right","bordercolor":"Black","borderwidth":1},"title":{"text":"UL AvgNumBytesInQueue (B)","font":{"color":"red","size":16}},"hovermode":"x","hoverlabel":{"namelength":20},"font":{"size":10},"autosize":false,"height":500,"width":1600},                        {"responsive": true}                    )                };                            </script>        </div>
```

Comment: It looks like you're fairly new to SO; welcome to the community! If you want great answers quickly, it's best to make your question reproducible. This includes sample data like the output from `dput()` or `reprex::reprex()` and any libraries you are using. What does the desired outcome look like? Check it out: [making R reproducible questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269).